# looping over a simple query with different values of "id"

Tags: postgresql, loops

I have a table with distinct id's that I want to use one by one for my query. Here is the pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
select distinct id
from table1

-- for every distinct id above, use that "id" in the query below - 

select xyz... 
where num = id
```

I want to do this using loops without using function / procedures etc.

The results for each loop run should be appended to the previous results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a loop if you need all records to be appended.
you can use a subquery as below:

```
select * from table2
where num in (select id from table1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was an example piece of code! I intend to write a complex query which I have replaced with xyz, can you please help?

Comment: Why do you think that makes a structural difference. Virtually always using 'loop' is the wrong approach. Moreover, loop is a psql construct, it is not a SQL construct. So *using loops without using function / procedures* or an anonymous *do ...*   block **cannot be done**.

Comment: okay thanks, so if I make a function, can I do this using loops?

Comment: Note that the `distinct` in the sub-query is unnecessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct. Updated answer.